# Why aren't template expressions simplified internally?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following example doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int index, template <typename> class Head,
        template <typename> class... Tail>
struct TemplateTupleElement {
    template <typename T>
    using Type =
            typename TemplateTupleElement<index - 1, Tail...>::template Type<T>;
};

template <template <typename> class Head, template <typename> class... Tail>
struct TemplateTupleElement<0, Head, Tail...> {
    template <typename T>
    using Type = Head<T>;
};

template <typename T>
class Dummy {
};

template <template <typename> class T>
class TemplateDummy {
public:
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Template" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
class TemplateDummy<Dummy> {
public:
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TemplateDummy<TemplateTupleElement<0, Dummy, Dummy>::Type>::print();
    TemplateDummy<TemplateTupleElement<1, Dummy, Dummy>::Type>::print();

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
Specialization
Specialization
```

However, the output of the program compiled with g++ ((Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) 5.3.0 20151204):

```
Specialization
Template
```

And the output with Clang (version 3.4-1ubuntu3) is:

```
Template
Template
```

I can understand that internally the compiler represents the two template expressions differently:

1. `Dummy`
2. `TemplateTupleElement<1, Dummy, Dummy>::Type`

Why isn't the second expression "simplified" into the first expression by g++, and why doesn't Clang map the expression correctly with either tuple indices?

Comment: `template <typename> typename T` isn't valid C++11 syntax, btw.

Comment: Clang gives me two `Template`s. Odd that GCC differs.

Comment: @sleep Fixed to remove minor C++14 syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @chris Thanks, I'll check it out using Clang

Comment: I am pretty sure there was an ambiguity about this at one point, if any alias is the same template as the template it aliases, and I vaguely recall a defect report.  As you are testing with a year old compiler, it might not have all resolved defects?

Comment: It does indeed produce a different result with Clang (version 3.4-1ubuntu3), but the result is the same with g++ version 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1 (6.1.1 20160511). Could this be undefined behaviour, or a gap in the specifications?

Comment: I suspect the key to this is `T` ? That is to say, it's fairly trivial for a compiler to determine whether two types T1 and T2 are equal. But aren't two class templates `T1<U>` and `T2<U>` equal _if and only if_ they result in the same instantiated type for any type `U`? Because the compiler cannot determine that (halting problem, of course).

Comment: http://wg21.link/cwg1286 @Yakk There still is.